# Suspend / Hibernate cannot resume laptop

Tags: linux, configuration

I'm trying to configure Suspend/Hibernate with my laptop and I issued some troubles.
I noticed the following troubles:

**Suspend :**
- Switching the lid off of my laptop : When I switch the lid on of the laptop, nothing happens. I must push down the power button to force the shutdown and then switch on the laptop.
- Typing `systemctl suspend` : same as previously.

**Hibernate :**
- Typing `systemctl hibernate` : the laptop seems to shutdown

I read those following links for helping me :
[Hibernate with swap file](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition)
[Suspend and hibernate](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate)

**My system :**

```
4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**My swap :**

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=403661c1-c7b4-47a8-9493-c5c0262ce14e /      ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=BF40-CD4F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/swap           swap            swap    defaults        0       0
```

**What I've done :**

- Create swap file

  ```
  $ fallocate -l 8g /swap  
  $ mkswap /swap
  ```
- Add swappiness

  ```
  sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1

  $ cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep swappiness
  vm.swappiness=1
  $ swapon /swap
  ```
- Configure grub

  ```
  $ cat /etc/default/grub | grep -i grub_cmdline_linux_default
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=/swap resume_offset=60354560 quiet splash"

  $ sudo filefrag -v /swap | head -n4
  Filesystem type is: ef53
  File size of /swap is 8589934592 (2097152 blocks of 4096 bytes)
  ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
  0:        0..       0:   60354560..  60354560:      1:
  ```

According to previous links I could configure `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` but there is no file like this in my system.
So, I don't really know how to configure my `initramfs`.

Here is my configuration from `/sys/power` :

```
$ cat /sys/power/disk
[platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume 
$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]
$ cat /sys/power/image_size
3261943808
$ cat /sys/power/resume
0:0
```

Could you give me some hints to make a step forward. Thanks you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks you for suggestion. I will try on those places.